# Publish to topic via launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to publish to a topic with a custom message type from within a launch file?

In a launch-file I launch several robots from external packages which I want to register to my running platform as they are launched.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230465/publish-to-topic-via-launch-file/) by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2016-03-29

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run `rostopic pub` from within a launch file with:

```
<node pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" name="rostopic" args="pub {pub args}"/>
```

where `{pub args}` are the arguments to `rostopic pub` to make it publish the way you want it to.

You may also want to change `name="rostopic"` to something specific to each robot, if there will be multiple copies of this running with the same ros master.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Siphax](https://answers.ros.org/users/89540/siphax/) on 2021-11-12**:
Hi, please can you help me,i have project arm robot with ROS in Raspberry, i know how run two arduino same time but i need publish different valor of just each topic , the commade is :

rostopic pub servo4 std_msgs/UInt16 180

<node pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" name="rostopic" args="pub {pub args}"

How can I use that ? For example, the arm needs the initial position of this arm to be 6 degrees  of liberty. We need to publish six different topics. i thinking this parameters but i don't know if this is true :

pkg = rostopic

type = pub servo4

name = std_msgs/UInt

args = entre 0  to 180